# Google App Script .getDisplayValue() not getting some displayed values when MATCH of IMPORTRANGE range is used

Tags: google-apps-script

I've noticed that `range.getDisplayValues()` is not getting some of my values that are obviously displayed and visible in the cells.

This is what I have done:

1. have a `sheet (#1)` that is an `IMPORTRANGE()` bringing in values from a second spreadsheet.

SHEET #1

```
| Cell A1 "=IMPORTRANGE("URL","sheet0!A:B")"

| Column A | Column B |

| -------- | -------- |

| Cell 1   | Cell 2   |

| Cell 3   | Cell 4   |
```

2. create a `sheet (#2)` that get a value from `MATCH` on the first `sheet (#1)`

SHEET #2

```
| Column A                         | Column B |

| --------                         | -------- |

| =Match("Cell 3", Sheet #1!A:A,0) | Something   |
```

The display value seen for the Match is "`2`" and that is displayed in `A1`

3. run a script that gets the `DISPLAY VALUES` from the `sheet #2`

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); //active being #2
var range=sheet.getRange("A1:B1");
var values=range.getDisplayValues();

Logger.log("*:"+values);// Output: *: ,Something
```

The first cell reported value through Logger is empty, no value, even though I can see it on the screen.

The output of the Logger should be: "`*:2,something`"

Comment: There are many problems using Google Apps Script and cell formulas together.  Personally, I avoid cell formulas altogether.

Comment: I did a quick test and the script actually worked for me. I got the output: `*:1,` in my test. I can see you are working with `getActiveSheet()`, are you making sure that the active sheet you are working on is the one that contains the result from the `MATCH` formula?

Comment: Yes, my test is actually not the exact use, but I get about 100 cells of data from one range and the only cell that does not come through is using this example.  All data on either side and other formulas all work fine.  I can't give the actual case because it is very complicated and involved, but a short test confirmed this for me with .getSheetByName() and just the single cell all by itself...nothing.  Not sure if the IMPORTRANGE is unique in some way.  Will be testing a lot.

Comment: Could you share the file you are using for your test? I was not able to reproduce the exact behavior on my testing so I think it would be better if you could share the file of your example to see the type of data that you are managing.